# Grouping XML nodes from different parents

Tags: xslt

I'm frustratingly new to xslt and have a question that I just can't seem to find an answer for. I'm applying a transformation to an xml file then using fo to output it to a .pdf. The input file (xml) comes from a billing system and we want to output it as a pdf that can be mailed to customers as a bill. I'm using xslt 1.0 and fop is generating the pdf. I'm having trouble grouping similarly named nodes (TAX) from 2 different parents (CHARGES and OTHER_CHARGES). Here's an example:
(Input file)

```
<BILL>
    <CHARGES PARENT_ID="123456" CUSTOMER="MR. JONES">
        <CHARGE NAME="CHARGE1" AMOUNT="10000">
            <TAXES>
                <TAX NAME="FEDERAL" AMOUNT="200"/>
                <TAX NAME="STATE" AMOUNT="50">
            </TAXES>
        </CHARGE>
    </CHARGES>
    <OTHER_CHARGES PARENT_ID="123456" CUSTOMER="MR_JONES">
        <OTHER_CHARGE NAME="OTHER_CHARGE1">
            <TAXES>
                <TAX NAME="FEDERAL" AMOUNT="150"/>
            </TAXES>
        </OTHER_CHARGE>
    </OTHER_CHARGES>
</BILL>
```

I want the total taxes for items billed so that the pdf output looks something like this

TAXES

FEDERAL - $350 
STATE - $50

With the total taxes grouped by name with their totals, despite coming from different nodes. I have a limited understanding of keys and grouping, but I can't seem to find that one magic example that flicks the switch in my brain.

Comment: could you post your xslt you're using so far? Is the NAME Attribute of the TAX Element somehow limited to a smaller set of values?

Comment: So why grouping? You just need `sum(*/*/TAXES/TAX[@NAME = 'FEDERAL']/@AMOUNT)` and `sum(*/*/TAXES/TAX[@NAME = 'STATE']/@AMOUNT)`. What should be grouped?

Comment: @Fack - The example is simplified, so there could be more than just FEDERAL or STATE. There could be some tax applied that we've never heard of. That's why I'm trying to group all nodes named tax together. If I knew all of the different taxes that could be applied, then I would gladly try not to group anything.

Comment: I think this is because, "FEDERAL" and "STATE" are just examples of the names and could vary in a wide range of names? Is this right? If its just the two names Flack's solution should do it.

Comment: @theUncannyValley Please provided a useful XML sample then.

Comment: @theUncannyValley Is XSLT 1.0 a constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kTaxes" match="TAX" use="@NAME"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            */*/TAXES/TAX[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kTaxes', @NAME)[1])]
            "/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TAX">
        <xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kTaxes', @NAME)/@AMOUNT)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to a slightly more complicated document:

```
<BILL>
    <CHARGES PARENT_ID="123456" CUSTOMER="MR. JONES">
        <CHARGE NAME="CHARGE1" AMOUNT="10000">
            <TAXES>
                <TAX NAME="FEDERAL" AMOUNT="200"/>
                <TAX NAME="STATE" AMOUNT="50"/>
                <TAX NAME="HEALTH" AMOUNT="300"/>
            </TAXES>
        </CHARGE>   
    </CHARGES>
    <OTHER_CHARGES PARENT_ID="123456" CUSTOMER="MR_JONES">
        <OTHER_CHARGE NAME="OTHER_CHARGE1">
            <TAXES>
                <TAX NAME="FEDERAL" AMOUNT="150"/>
                <TAX NAME="MATERNITY" AMOUNT="150"/>
                <TAX NAME="HEALTH" AMOUNT="600"/>
            </TAXES>
        </OTHER_CHARGE>
    </OTHER_CHARGES>
</BILL>
```

Correct result will be:

```
FEDERAL: 350
STATE: 50
HEALTH: 900
MATERNITY: 150
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you could do (if you have to stick with XSLT 1.0) is:

- Select all Taxes in a varibale

`<xs:variable name="taxes" select="//TAX"/>`

- Then Select the distinct TAX Names like this:

`<xs:variable name="distict_taxes" select="//$taxes[not(@NAME=preceding::TAX/@NAME)"/>`

- Then iterate through this distinct taxes by for-each putting the name into variable $taxname and do:

`<xs:value-of select="sum(//*/TAXES/TAX[@NAME=$taxname]/@AMOUNT)"/>`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think this has me on the right path at least. I'm quite new to this, so I'm suffering from an acute case of 'not knowing what the hell I'm doing'. I'll let you know how it turns out.

Comment: That XPath 1.0 "first of a kind" expression has poorer performace than XSLT grouping.

Comment: @Alejandro... yes... and? What is wrong with a XSLT 1.0 solution when in the question a XSLT 1.0 Solution is wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, then try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

    <xsl:template match="BILL">
        <report>
            <xsl:for-each-group select=".//TAX" group-by="@NAME">
                <tax>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of
                            select="current-grouping-key()" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="total">
                        <xsl:value-of 
                            select="sum(current-group()/@AMOUNT)" />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </tax>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </report>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<report>
    <tax name="FEDERAL" total="350"/>
    <tax name="STATE" total="50"/>
</report>
```

Comment: +1 This is a correct XSLT 2.0 solution. But you should better use a relative path to `TAX` element if you are going to match `BILL` elements.

Comment: @Alejandro: could you please explain better your comment?

Comment: Yes. If you are going to group by `BILL` don't use every `TAX`, use only it's decendants, like `.//TAX` or `*/*/*/TAX`, otherwise worng result could come up with several `BILL` elements in the document.

Comment: @Alejandro: thanks! I updated my answer. I didn't think about it, because I assumed `BILL` to be the root element of the XML, which may not be the case.